# await HttpClient.PostAsync method compilation error

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to make a post request with the the following code:

```
string resourceAddress = "url";
string postBody = "jsonbody";
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage x = await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress, new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

I got this compilation error:
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method

Any Ideas? PostAsync returns `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`...

Comment: Well, is your method `async`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method must be marked as `async`:

```
public async ReturnType MethodName()
{
     string resourceAddress = "url";
     string postBody = "jsonbody";
     var httpClient = new HttpClient();
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
     HttpResponseMessage x = await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress, new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```

Not knowing neither the return type of your method nor the method name and it's arguments, I have used vague names and no parameters. You have to replace them with the real one.

Generally, whenever you want to make use of `await` operator (This is happening when you want to make an asynchronous call), you have to use also the `async` operator. The `async` operator is used to denote that you are going to `await` something. Then the compiler builds for you a state machine that is used by the runtime to execute your code asynchronously.

Comment: @TomerZvirsh You are welcome. I am  glad that I helped.